# How to make function work multiple times

Tags: javascript

```js
var change = function() {
  var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
  var count = 0;
  count++;
  var color = "";
  var colors = ["#ff6051", "#ff9f51", "#ffdf51", "#b6ff51", "#51adff", "#3e65c1", "#6414ef"];
  for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    if (count == i + 1) {
      color = colors[i];
    }
  }
  elem[0].style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="change()">Click me</button>
```

I want the background color of the body to change when I click the button.
But the number of variable "count" doesn't seem to increase. What should I do to make the number increase?

Comment: In this function you set count to zero then you increment it, so the answer will always be the same. 0, then 0++.

Comment: What happens after count reaches 8?

Comment: @Yerim Kang, please check this option to achieve similar result- https://codepen.io/divyar34/pen/EbZxPm

Comment: @divyareddy thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the variabe **count** outside the function so that it gets the global scope whenever you update.

**DEMO**

```js
var count = 0;
var change = function() {
  var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("body");

  count++;
  console.log('##count',count);
  var color = "";
  var colors = ["#ff6051", "#ff9f51", "#ffdf51", "#b6ff51", "#51adff", "#3e65c1", "#6414ef"];
  for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    if (count == i + 1) {
      color = colors[i];
    }
  }
  elem[0].style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="change()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: What happens after count reaches 8?

Answer (score 1):

The `count` variable has local scope, so it will not exist after the anonymous function expression referred by `change` variable finishes execution. For it to sustain its life time across repeated function calls on button click action it should be declared in global scope outside the anonymous function expression:

```js
var count = 0; //now count has global scope.
    var change = function() {
      var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
     
      count++;
      var color = "";
      var colors = ["#ff6051", "#ff9f51", "#ffdf51", "#b6ff51", "#51adff", "#3e65c1", "#6414ef"];
      for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        if (count == i + 1) {
          color = colors[i];
        }
      }
      elem[0].style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="change()">Click me</button>
```

**Note**: You should also consider giving some default color inside the `for` loop as after 7 clicks it will be setting the `backgroundColor` to empty string.

```
var color = "#000000"; //default black color may be
```

Comment: What happens after count reaches 8?

Comment: In that case `for` loop will not run and `elem`'s `backgroundColor` property would get set to empty string.

Comment: Umm, no. For loop WILL run, it just won't be able to reach 8 for `i`

Comment: What's the loop for?

Comment: @nnnnnn To change the background color of the page dynamically every time user clicks the button.

Comment: No, that's what the function is for. You don't need a loop to access an array element when you already have a variable, `count` that can be used as the array index.

Comment: yes @nnnnnn, we can avoid for loop and not required to change background color from array - https://codepen.io/divyar34/pen/EbZxPm

Answer (score 1):

Each call to your function is resetting count to 0 because you are setting it to zero on the second line of the function.

If you set it to 0 outside the function once, this will solve the count problem.

However, there is an additional problem (that you didn't mention): after counting to 7, you run out of colours in your array because count exceeds the bounds of the array. I would lose the for loop since it is unnecessary (use count to index into the array instead) and just reset count when it reaches the size of the array.

```js
var count = 0;
var colors = ["#ff6051", "#ff9f51", "#ffdf51", "#b6ff51", "#51adff", "#3e65c1", "#6414ef"];
var change = function() {
    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
    if (count == colors.length) {
        count = 0;
    }
    elem[0].style.backgroundColor = colors[count];
    count++;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="change()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Not bad, but two inherent issues: (1) you are now polluting the global namespace (2) you're always skipping the first color, which should be more red

Comment: @vol7ron - good point. I should fix that (since I introduced that problem).

Answer (score 1):

Without changing your code too much, you can avoid the loop and iterate over the array by comparing the current color.  This also avoids holding a count iterator.

**Note:**

- Some browsers return `backgroundColor` as an rgb value (e.g., `rgb( ###, ###, ###)`), which is why `rgb2hex` is used to convert the it to the hex value like that stored in the `colors` array.

```js
var change = function() {

  var el           = document.querySelector("body");
  var colors       = ["#ff6051", "#ff9f51", "#ffdf51", "#b6ff51", "#51adff", "#3e65c1", "#6414ef"];
  var currentColor = rgb2hex( el.style.backgroundColor );
  var colorIndex   = colors.indexOf( currentColor );

  // If at last color, cycle back to front
  if (colorIndex == colors.length-1)
    colorIndex = -1;

  el.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex + 1];
}



/** Converts decimal to hex **/
function hex(x) {
  return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
}

/** Converts rgb string to hex string **/
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
  if (rgb.search("rgb") == -1)
    return rgb;
  else {
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(\d+))?\)$/);
    return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="change()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option
No need of **for** loop
After 7 clicks , loop runs again
One issue with your code is, first background color will always be skipped due **i+1** and after 7 clicks , it comes back to white background

```
var count = 0;
var colors = ["#ff6051", "#ff9f51", "#ffdf51", "#b6ff51", "#51adff", "#3e65c1", "#6414ef"];


var change = function() {
  if(count == colors.length + 1){
    count =0;
  }
  ++count;
  var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
  elem[0].style.backgroundColor = colors[count];
}
```

https://codepen.io/divyar34/pen/EbZxPm

Answer (score 0):

You can **generically** count the invocations of any function by "lifting" the function (wrapping it) with a function that just does that.
This leaves you with a simple function that doesn't need to know if it is being counted, which you can wrap with a counter only when you need it.

```
function countingWrapper(f,reportf)
{
    var counter = 0;
    return function()
    {
      reportf( ++counter)
      return f.apply(this, arguments);     
    }
}

function doSomething() { console.log('boo!'); }
function reportSomething(n) { console.log('did something '+ n + ' times.')}

var newDoSomething = countingWrapper(doSomething, reportSomething);

newDoSomething();
newDoSomething();
newSoSomething();
```